# Why does the callback function for reduce take four parameters?

Tags: javascript, callback, reduce, optional-parameters

In studying the reduce method I'm not quite sure why the callback passed in needs the third and fourth parameters, index and array. In the example from the MDN:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

A lot of other uses for the array reduce method or underscore reduce function I've studied only make use of the first two parameters for the `callback`: `previousValue` (sometimes seen as `accumulator`) and `currentValue` (aka `elem`, the value of the current index).

Why is reduce sometimes written with `callback` taking four parameters and sometimes written with only `previousValue` and `currentValue`?

What would be a case where the `index` and `array` parameters are needed?

Should all four parameters always be given in a function definition for reduce in case an application of reduce requires the third or fourth parameters?

Comment: no there is no need to give all 4 params always, you could just use the first 2 params like `function(previousValue, currentValue){}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a (slightly) less-contrived example to sum up unique values in an array, skipping duplicates, using the *index* and *array* arguments to find unique values:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(currentValue) === index ? // value used already?
         previousValue + currentValue :  // not used yet, add to sum
         previousValue; // used already, skip currentValue
}); // == 6  ( 0+1+2+3 )
```

live demo: http://pagedemos.com/fn764n659ama/1/

side note: [].reduce() runs quite a bit faster in V8  by specifying all four arguments as formal parameters on the callback, regardless of if they are used by the code inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to use the first two parameters, it is perfectly fine to leave the last two out in the function arguments list. In that case the last two arguments will just be ignored. To sum the array, this is a perfectly acceptable way to do it:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

The last two parameters, `index` and `array` just give you extra information in case you need it. For example, say you wanted to sum up the all the elements in the array multiplied by their mirror element, that is, given the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` you wanted to output

```
(0 * 4) + (1 * 3) + (2 * 2) + (3 * 1) + (4 * 0)
```

then you would have to use the last two parameters:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue * array[array.length - index - 1];
});
```

Admittedly, this is a somewhat contrived example, but I'm having a hard time coming up with an example that doesn't seem contrived. In any event, the last two parameters do occasionally come in handy.